# Questions from a python beginner

Tags: python

for a code saying:

```
list=[]
for _ in range(25):
     x = turtle.Turtle()
     list.append(x)
```

seems like the list can make me use the different turtles in 25 same variable x is that?
how could it possible and can you explain the specific reason for this code?

Comment: `x` is just a temporary variable.  What's happening is that 25 Turtles are being created and added to the List named `list`.  What ends up in `list` is all that matters.

Comment: I know what you means but actually I'm confused with the fact that why I can still control those 25 turtles by using list[],does that means everytime a element get into a list,the list will give it a new "defination"for computer to control it after the x has lost the right of controling the previous turtles? thanks alot

Comment: No, by using the in range command you determine for how many elements/ places in the list the following block is executed.
The function knows that - whatever comes after ":" - shall be done 25 times. Therefore, you start with an empty list that gets filled one by one every round until it counts 25 elements, in which case the for loop is done and the algorithm terminates.

Answer (score 1):

Lets dissect:

```
for _ in range(25):
```

In the above line, the "_" is usually used when you intend to ignore the value.
So technically, you are just running the content of the loop 25 times

```
x = turtle.Turtle()
list.append(x)
```

This creates an instance of the class `Turtle` and assigns to the variable x, which we append to our list.

Remember, every time you create an instance and assign to `x` the previous reference is lost and new reference is assigned.

If it helps, the cleaner version would just be:

```
for _ in range(25):
  list.append(turtle.Turtle())
```

or even better:

```
list = [turtle.Turtle() for _ in range(25)]
```

^^ This says to create a list of size 25 with each element an instance of Turtle.

Comment: `[turtle.Turtle()] * 25`  is wrong, as the list will 25 references to a single object.

Comment: I know what you means but actually I'm confused with the fact that why I can still control those 25 turtles by using list[],does that means everytime a element get into a list,the list will give it a new "defination"for computer to control it?thanks a lot!

Comment: Turtle is a class. Think of it as `creating` a new different Turtle and storing those references in your list. So lets suppose, if your teacher asks you `whats the second Turtle doing?`, you can access the particular turtle like: `list[1]`

Answer (score 0):

i am unsure with what you mean by same variable X.

every time the loop starts again the variable is over written, which means every iteration the variable X is another instance of Turtle. Concluding with 25 different turtles in list.

Comment: That's actually what my teacher gave to me,and maybe you can check the answer above!Thank you for thinking for my problem!